# Single word request: practice based on non-strict criteria

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english, academic-writing

**Context:**

Clinical decision making is highly varying, as there are no strict criteria between operative and nonoperative management.

**How to say this with one academically suitable word?**

> Clinical decision making is **loose/slipshod**

Comment: We like to help those who have first done a little research themselves. However, your question is clear and well-defined in a medical context and it is hard to see how you could have researched it in a mathematical/physical context without that expertise, which would of course have obviated the need for the question! I have therefore answered it as best I can.

Comment: I would be inclined to disagree with the use of a term that makes the subject sound to be "ill-defined" or even worse. The subject is medical and to lead an audience to believe that the medical profession is in disarray and running around like headless chickens does not seem to be the best approach. Surely a better approach would be that "Clinical decision making is highly variable, as there are no defined criteria between operative and nonoperative management".

Comment: @brad we are concerned with meaning, not with the maintenance of appearances. To deny the certainty of decisions is not to deny the worth of the process of decision-making.

Comment: @Anton I would agree with you. However, the original sentence does not reflect a "certainty of decisions" but does reflect a "highly variable" one. It is yourself that has assumed "certainty of decisions" is questionable as opposed to varied.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The study compared the adherence of clinical practice to internationally accepted clinical guidelines/standards, revealing discrepancies between the two.

Comment: 'Subjective', unlike 'slipshod', allows that many good decisions may be made.

Comment: @Brad Reference to uncertainty is to deal with the opinion you express in your comment and has nothing to do directly with the question.

Comment: @Anton correct, that is why I posted at as a comment not an Answer. However to expand my explanation " the opinion you express in your comment and has nothing to do directly with the question" correct, but it does with relation to an answer. The Question states "How to say this with one academically suitable word?" academically...adverb....in a way that relates to studying and thinking, not practical skills: Alas, loose/slipshod or  ill-conditioned, ill-defined, ill-posed are not words that I associate with an academic paper. Edwin Ashworth's "Subjective" would fit rather well though.

Comment: @Brad the references I give illustrate the academic use of ill-conditioned and ill-posed in mathematical and physical sciences. They are not judgemental terms, merely useful ways of describing circumstances such as in the quotations I give. And as such they fit the question, where small differences in the underlying criteria lead to large difference in the result, making it highly variable. This is not *subjective*, because subjective decision making is more a matter of opinion or prejudice than of imperfections or incompleteness in the basic criteria in an objective decision process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An academically suitable word may be one of the hyphenated adjectives based (amusingly, given your medical context) on *ill*. All are based on the idea that a solution or decision is to be based on some information but that the information is too poor to lead to a reliable result, or of such a nature that the result is very sensitive to small changes in the information.

Three candidates are *ill-conditioned*, *ill-defined*, *ill-posed*.

> ill-defined = not clearly explained, described, or shown
>
> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ill-defined)

> ill-conditioned = In non-mathematical terms, an ill-conditioned problem is one where, for a small change in the inputs (the independent variables or the right-hand-side of an equation) there is a large change in the answer or dependent variable. This means that the correct solution/answer to the equation becomes hard to find
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number)

> ill-posed:
>
> The mathematical term well-posed problem stems from a definition given by 20th-century French mathematician Jacques Hadamard. He believed that mathematical models of physical phenomena should have the properties that:
>
> a solution exists; the solution is unique; the solution's behaviour changes continuously with the initial conditions.
>
> Examples of archetypal well-posed problems include the Dirichlet problem for Laplace's equation, and the heat equation with specified initial conditions. These might be regarded as 'natural' problems in that there are physical processes modelled by these problems.
>
> Problems that are not well-posed in the sense of Hadamard are termed **ill-posed**. Inverse problems are often ill-posed. For example, the inverse heat equation, deducing a previous distribution of temperature from final data, is not well-posed in that the solution is highly sensitive to changes in the final data.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-posed_problem)

The academic precision of the last term may be the best fit to your specification.